# How to send image via mms in ios 7+ programmatically?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

How to send image via mms in ios 7+ programmatically ?
I have image name saved locally and I need to sendvia mms.
Does ios support this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this by two ways, 
1 - By using MFMessageComposeViewController
2 - By MMS

In the first way you can send the image via iMessage
In the second way you can send MMS via Career network

For 1st process the code is

```
-(void)sendSMSto:(NSString *)number withImage:(UIImage *)sentImage{
 MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    NSMutableString *messageBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    picker.recipients = number?[NSArray arrayWithObject:number]:nil;// your recipient number or self for testing
    [picker setBody:messageBody];

    if ([picker respondsToSelector:@selector(addAttachmentData:typeIdentifier:filename:)]) {
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sentImage);
        [picker addAttachmentData:imageData typeIdentifier:(@"public.image") filename:@"emoji.png"];
    }

    picker.body = messageBody;
    ELogs(@"Picker -- %@",picker.body);
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
       ELogs(@"SMS fired");
    }];
}
}
```

For second approach
use the UIPasteboard to copy the image and then paste it in the MMS screen

the code is

```
-(void)sendSMSto:(NSString *)number withImage:(UIImage *)sentImage{
if (sentImage) {
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    pasteboard.persistent = YES;
    pasteboard.image = sentImage;
}

//For sms through network career
NSString *phoneToCall = @"sms:";
NSString *phoneToCallEncoded = [phoneToCall stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:phoneToCallEncoded];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

}
```

Please accept the answer, if you find this useful

Comment: @Janmejaya Thanks for reply, seconds works, just question for first, what is a picker ? Thanks again.

Comment: @PaolaJ. picker is an object of class MFMessageController. I am Editing the answer for you